# Ruby Singleton Attribute Defaults

Tags: ruby, singleton

I'm attempting to create a class that uses the Singleton module:

```
class Foo
  include Singleton

  # def initialize
  #   puts "Initialized!"
  # end  

  singleton_class.class_eval do
    attr_accessor :bar
  end
end
```

The problem here is that `bar` does not have a default/initial value. I've added a `initialize` method to my class in hopes that it would be invoked once but this doesn't seem to be the case. What is the proper way to ensure that `bar` has a value when this class is loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you implemented it the accessors for `@bar` are methods of the class `Foo`, thus you have define `@bar` as a class instance variable of `Foo`, not of the instance of `Foo`:

```
class Foo
  include Singleton
  @bar = 0
  singleton_class.class_eval do
    attr_accessor :bar
  end
end

Foo.bar
# => 0
```